# Marquee is not working when seek bar gets updated

Tags: android, audio, marquee, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm making a music player and have implemented a marquee for the song and artist name. But as soon as the seek bar gets updated, the text view comes back to the original position. So in this way, a kind of back and forth motion of text is seen.

Here is my XML code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/mainFullPlayerContainer"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"

   tools:context="com.musicplayer.integrated.sanket.music.MainFullPlayer"
    android:background="@color/defaultBackground">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_full_player_more"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_more" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_full_player_album_art"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/default_album_art"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />



<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:progressTint="@color/defaultTextColor"
    android:thumbTint="@color/defaultTextColor"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView_full_player_play"

    android:layout_marginBottom="37dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_full_player_play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_play_small" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_full_player_next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView_full_player_play"
    android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView_full_player_play"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_fast_next_small" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_full_player_prev"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView_full_player_play"
    android:layout_marginEnd="38dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView_full_player_play"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_rewind_prev_small" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_full_player_song"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView_full_player_album_art"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView_full_player_album_art"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_full_player_album_art"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Song Name"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_current_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0:00"
    android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
    android:textSize="12sp"

    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView_full_player_prev"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView_full_player_artist" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_total_length"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="5:00"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView_current_time"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_current_time"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView_full_player_artist" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_full_player_artist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView_full_player_song"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView_full_player_song"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_full_player_song"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="Artist"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Here is the design]

Here is my Java code:

```
public class MainFullPlayer extends AppCompatActivity {

 private static RelativeLayout  fullPlayer;
 private static ImageView fullPlayer_play , fullPlayer_next , 
 fullPlayer_prev,fullPlayer_album;
 private static TextView fullPlayer_song , fullPlayer_artist , 
 fullPlayer_currentTime , fullPlayer_maxTime;
 private    static SeekBar seekBar;
 private Songs song;
 private static Handler progressHandler;
 private static Runnable   progressRunnable;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_full_player);
    fullPlayer = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainFullPlayerContainer);
    fullPlayer_play = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_full_player_play);
    fullPlayer_next = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_full_player_next);
    fullPlayer_prev = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_full_player_prev);
    fullPlayer_album = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_full_player_album_art);
    fullPlayer_song = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_full_player_song);
    fullPlayer_artist = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_full_player_artist);
    fullPlayer_currentTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_current_time);
    fullPlayer_maxTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_total_length);

    fullPlayer_maxTime.setText(MusicPlayback.getTime(MusicPlayback.mediaPlayer.getDuration()));

    seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

    song = MusicPlayback.allTracks.get(MusicPlayback.songPosition);
    fullPlayer_song.setSelected(true);
    fullPlayer_artist.setSelected(true);
    fullPlayer_song.setText(song.getSongName());
    fullPlayer_artist.setText(song.getArtist());


    if(MusicPlayback.getPlayingStatus()){
        fullPlayer_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_pause_small);
    }
    else
    {
        fullPlayer_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play_small);
    }
    if(song.getAlbumArt()!= null){

        fullPlayer_album.setImageURI(Uri.parse(song.getAlbumArt()));
        fullPlayer.setBackground(FragmentAllTracks.d);
    }
    else{
        fullPlayer_album.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_album_art);
        fullPlayer.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 48, 48, 48));

    }
seekBar.setMax(MusicPlayback.mediaPlayer.getDuration());


    progressHandler = new Handler();

    progressRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            seekBar.setProgress(MusicPlayback.mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            fullPlayer_currentTime.setText(MusicPlayback.getTime(MusicPlayback.mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));


            progressHandler.postDelayed(progressRunnable,100);
        }
    };
    progressHandler.postDelayed(progressRunnable,100);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
  this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_exit_translate,R.anim.right_exit_translate);

}
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: Unable to get Marquee]

Comment: add `seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener()` listener, Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481977/android-seekbar-to-control-mediaplayer-progress

Comment: Kindly suggest me about how to get marquee effect. Read the description carefully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextView restarts Marquee when changing another TextView in same LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856875/textview-restarts-marquee-when-changing-another-textview-in-same-linearlayout)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this `MarqueeTextView` class, it automatically set fixed size for `TextView` so it won't re-measure (the reason cause restart scroll animation):

```
public class MarqueeTextView extends AppCompatTextView implements View.OnLayoutChangeListener {
    public MarqueeTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MarqueeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MarqueeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setSingleLine();
        setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
        setSelected(true);

        addOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFocused() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {
        if (hasWindowFocus) super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        if (focused) super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
                               int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = bottom - top;
        layoutParams.width = right - left;
        removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
        setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It happens because of this line inside the runnable:

`fullPlayer_currentTime.setText(MusicPlayback.getTime(MusicPlayback.mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));`

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13841982/10334697.

You have to set fixed size for your TextView.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of focus. Please set your textview like this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_full_player_song"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView_full_player_album_art"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView_full_player_album_art"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_full_player_album_art"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:text="Song Name"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

add this your TextView,

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: Sir kindly read the description and suggest me some ways to get rid of my problem. I'm using text view in order to display song and artist name in the big player. In order to updat seek bar I'm using handler thread. But after the implementation of the thread I'm unable to get marquee effect on the TextViews.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help me. :( I'm still unable to get marquee effect on the implementation of the thread for the seek bar.